# Передача по ссылке и nullptr

Tags: c++

Пишу функцию на с++ типа:

```
solve(vector<vector<int>> &matrix);
```

Вроде ничего сложного, просто передается аргумент по ссылке. Как я понял, с точки зрения ассемблера это просто адрес `matrix` положенный на стек. Решил протестировать 
ее, и на одном сайте на стек кладут `nullptr` и программа аварийно завершается.

Первый вопрос: можно ли на своем ПК встретить такую же ситуацию, когда при передаче аргумента по ссылке на стек кладется `nullptr`?

Второй вопрос: как же все-таки отловить такую ошибку, так как любое обращение к `matrix` сразу ведет к разыменование нулевого указателя и аварийному завершению?

Comment: Вы думаете неправильно, в терминах реализации. В C++ ссылка есть алиас объекта, его другое имя. И оно не может ссылаться на отсутствие объекта. Как оно там внутри, не настолько важно.

Answer (score 3):

В С++ ссылка не может содержать nullptr. Отсюда следует, что проверять на наличие nullptr смысла нет.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, если вы думаете, что кому-то не лень издеваться над кодом [вот так](http://ideone.com/5gz4Sw):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void f(int&i)
{
    cout << i << endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int& i = *static_cast<int*>(nullptr);
    f(i);
}
```

то можно на всякий случай вставить проверку:

```
void f(int&i)
{
    if (&i == nullptr) 
    { 
        cout << "Не надуришь!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Разве когда мы берем амперсанд от matrix мы не производим разыменование, а только потом взятие адреса?

Comment: Нет, какое разыменование, для чего? Просто получение адреса.

Comment: Разыменование указателя, не указывающего на объект - UB.